# Getting error Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Getting error Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'".

When trying to load wordpress admin add post in nginx server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in your nginx configuration file

add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" always;

Comment: This is a way to basically disable CSP and getting no additional security.